# Why does the cube have the fewest facets among (centrally) symmetric polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes

> "A body like the cube, which is bounded by a finite number of flat facets, is called a
> polytope. Among **symmetric polytopes**, the cube has the **fewest** possible facets, namely $2n$."

I am looking for **rigorous** proof and also **intuition** behind why this must be true. I'm thinking of doing something by contradiction, i.e. assuming less than $2n$ facets for a symmetric polytope and then going ahead from there?

I don't have much to add here in terms of *how I approached this*, because this isn't a problem - it is something I came across while reading some lecture notes! I could not find much on this online, and I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit:** It seems the author is talking about centrally symmetric polytopes, i.e. $x\in K$ whenever $-x\in K$.

Comment: Doesn't a tetrahedron have fewer facets than a cube?

Comment: You do make sense. Perhaps I've confused what they mean by symmetric? Please check Pg. 8 here and let me know if you find anything: http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf

Is a tetrahedron *centrally symmetric*? I think this would also depend on the choice of origin though.

Comment: As the top of page 8 notes they're talking about _centrally_ symmetric polytopes; that is, $x$ is in the polytope iff $-x$ is also in the polytope. Cubes work for that, but tetrahedra don't. (A standard 3D tetrahedron is obtained by picking vertices $(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)$ with an even number of minus signs. This definition makes it apparent that it's not centrally symmetric.)

Comment: Perhaps I should edit my question to include that!

Comment: One paper on arXiv ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.3661)) discussing Kalai's conjectures for cs-polytopes begins as such: "A convex $d$-polytope $P$ is centrally symmetric, or cs for short, if $P = −P$. Concerning face numbers, this implies that for $0 \leq i \leq d − 1$ the number of $i$-faces $f_i(P)$ is even and, since $P$ is
full-dimensional, that $\text{min} \{f_0(P), f_{d−1}(P)\} \geq 2d$." This implies that $f_{d-1}(P)$, the number of facets, is bounded below by $2d$. (Alas, I can't really penetrate the logic here...)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is equivalent to the question. @Semiclassical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By symmetry, any face should have an opposite face. So, your polytope should have at least two opposite faces. But the region bounded between two opposite hyperplanes is not bounded, you still have $n-1$ degrees of freedom inside the "slice" of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You choose another pair of independent (opposite) hyperplanes. These bound your region in an independent direction, but you still have $n-2$ directions along which it is unbounded. You have to continue until you have at least $2n$ faces to get a bounded region. Since a cube has exactly $2n$ faces, it is the polytope with the minimum possible number of them.

Comment: Thanks, amazing answer! I am wondering if we can make some parts more rigorous, such as: (i) Adding a pair of linearly independent (from the existing $2k$ hyperplanes) opposite hyperplanes, leaves the polytope *unbounded* in exactly $n-k-1$ directions. (ii) Do we say anything about the distance between these parallel hyperplanes? by "opposite" you mean parallel and separate by some distance $0<d\in\mathbb{R}$ right? Is this the same for all pairs or what? (iii) What does it mean to be ***unbounded along a direction***, in more mathematical terms?

Comment: I believe you can make this argument absolutely rigorous. By opposite hyperplane I mean: if one of them has equation $\langle w,x\rangle = b$, the opposite one is $\langle w,x\rangle =-b$. Every time in the process you can change your axis. For example you can choose your first new axis $x_1$ perpendicular to the first pair of hyperplanes and then your region is defined by $|x_1|\le d$ for some $d$, so clearly the rest of the variables are free. The distance between opposite faces can be different, it is irrelevant here. Any parallelepiped has the same number of faces than a cube.

Comment: Unbounded in some direction means that the projection of your body on that direction is unbounded. After choosing your $x_1$ axis as before, your region is unbounded in the direction of the rest of the axes.